# Possible Circular References in my Database Design

Tags: sql, entity-framework, database-design, circular-dependency

I am playing around with EF and Autofixture. I tried to get Autofixture to generate some data for me but it came back saying it found circular reference in my objects.

I am not sure how to fix though.

[image]

A grocery lit can have many users (think of a family sharing the same list)

A user can have a collection of preferred stores that they always go and shop at.

A grocery list can of course have many shopping list items

A user can specify that a certain item can only be bought at a certain store (UsersPreferredStore can have many GroceryListItems)

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 7 tables :

Users N : M Grocery list -> therefore three tables. One for users, one for grocery lists and one to link both.

Users N : M Stores -> two more tables, one for stores and one to link users and stores

Grocery List 1 : N GroceryListItems -> One table for shopping list items with the grocery list id as a FK.

Store N : M GroceryListItems -> One more table to link stores and shopping list items

[image]

Comment: I added a image to help better visualize it.

Comment: @Jonysuise - Wow did not think this would be the result. I have a few more circular references(it just seems so easy to make especially when your doing code first) I am going to have like 50 tables now and it will be so complex. What is the advantage of this again?

Comment: Btw is there some tool I can use to quickly test my database or my domains(I am using Code First EF) for these dependencies?